# Is there a way to call the llvm `llc` command from my C project?

Tags: c, cmake, linker, llvm, llc

I'm trying to use the llc command from llvm in my C compiler project, but I don't know how to use it. I've tried linking llvm libraries in cmake, but I don't know which libraries to link if I want `llc`. Any help would be fine, thanks!

Comment: [`system()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)?

Comment: @MikeCAT generally `system` is discouraged - since it leaves you with no control of the created process, though I suppose it might work depending on the circumstance

Comment: `system` is dangerous if you don't do proper quoting when creating the command string. It uses the shell to parse and execute the command line. Just think what would happen if you tried pass the filename `myfile; rm -rf /` to `llc`.

Answer (score 0):

Now it kind of depends on the OS, but yes there are ways to open a subprocess through the system shell

Under UNIX-y systems you can use `popen` (https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen), which allows you to open and communicate with a subprocess (in this case `llc`).

Under Windows it seems like `_popen` has similar functionality - though I've never personally used it so you may need to read [the MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen?view=msvc-160)

Comment: Just like `system`, `popen` relies on the shell to parse and evaluate a command string. The same security considerations apply.

Comment: @HAL9000 generally, calling any executable has security implications since, from the perspective of your program, its effectively arbitrary code. For the purposes of calling a linker, many compilers use the shell to invoke a secondary program and so I think its acceptable in this scenario - it is an important consideration in some situations though of course

Comment: This is not about trusting `llc`, which for most practical use may be considered a binary blob. This is about trust in the program you write yourself and its ability to handle data from untrusted sources. If you are not careful when creating the command string for `popen` or `system` when processing untrusted data, an attacker could with specially crafted data, run arbitary commands. It is basically the same problem as with SQL-injection.

Comment: @HAL9000 But this is a compiler? The input data is inherently user generated...

Comment: This is not about `llc` being a compiler or processing data. Its is about the data you are processing in your program and using to build a command line for `system` or `popen` to parse and execute. What if an untrusted user has the possibility to influence the optimization flag used when calling `llc`, and tricks your program to execute with the optimization flag `-O;rm -rf /;`? Since the shell is used to parse and execute the command line, this would be bad. By using `fork`/`exec` this would have been a no-issue. This are real world issues when programs are used as backends for websites.

Comment: @HAL9000 you misunderstand me - the *OP* is writing a compiler and invoking llc - the input is inherently arbitrary since (presumably) there is flag passthrough

Comment: Yes flag passthrough is *exatly* what I am talking about. The user of the compiler OP is writing would expect that the flag `-O;rm -rf /;` would get passed unmodified to `llc`, and not be interpreted by the shell as `something -O;rm -rf /; somethingelse`. Note the special meaning `;` has to the shell.

Comment: Final comment before i check out of this discussion: If Stackoverflow whould have written in its backend: `ssprintf(cmd, "add_comment %d %d %s", post_id, user_id, text); system(cmd);`, then all my uses of `;rm -rf /;` in these comments would have been *"interesting"*...